# How to remove small vertical line in axis of a barplot with pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis} [
    ybar,
    grid=none,
    bar width=0.06cm,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={}, % the ylabel must precede a # symbol.
    xlabel={},
    symbolic x coords={A, B, C, D, E}, % these are the specification of coordinates on the x-axis.
    xtick=data,
      % this command is used to mention the y-axis points on the top of the particular bar.
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]

\addplot coordinates {(A,10) (B,70) (C,70) (D,80) (E,40) };

\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I would like to remove these little tiny lines in the upper part of the border and the lower part of the border that are above the letters. I thought that grid=none would do it, but it doesn't help, and I can't find out what to toggle.

Comment: Does adding `every x tick/.style={/pgfplots/major tick length=0pt}` give you what you want?